# Social Login with Nestjs. Issues with REST API

Tags: angular, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js, nestjs

I'm implementing Google login with Nestjs, Passport and oauth2. Also I'm trying to connect my Nestjs REST API app with an Angular 10 frontend.

In my auth.controller.js I have:

```
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  async googleAuth(@Req() req) {}

  @Get('google/redirect')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  async googleLoginRedirect(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response): Promise<any> {

    // show current user
    console.log(req.user);

          return {
            statusCode: HttpStatus.OK,
            payload: req.user,
          };
  }
```

strategy.google.ts:

```
import {default as config} from '../../config';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy, VerifyCallback } from 'passport-google-oauth20';

import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {

  constructor() {
    super({
      clientID: config.google.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: config.google.GOOGLE_SECRET,
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/redirect',
      //callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8100/menu/main',
      scope: ['email', 'profile'],
    });
  }

  async validate (accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: any, done: VerifyCallback): Promise<any> {
    const { name, emails, photos } = profile
    const user = {
      email: emails[0].value,
      firstName: name.givenName,
      lastName: name.familyName,
      picture: photos[0].value,
      accessToken
    }
    done(null, user);
  }
}
```

When sending a http GET request to 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/redirect' as my callback url, I can get the desired response (authenticated user) in console:

```
Wed May 12 2021 21:16:10 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) - [Request]  - {}
{
  email: 'jdoe@gmail.com',
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  picture: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJzw91B2GNWHUkh6yzlwSmbZKQOmS0_NB-tAiViS=s96-c',
  accessToken: 'ya29.a0AfH6SMACc_xs2RSYB6vg5Kwl4-Nta_89RZUgHt9qP20bKpf2TRing2Pvtfo0tBu61og-CIYCSfJPe8CI36busf7I3smWBQ4gozTkloLc7o-uw-TjXSfb3PNdc3tOb3jvHqQTTlxCPq0tIa1yCTbuYEMLxR94'
}
```

Also I'm able to access redirect page with the right response in browser.

But doing the same in curl I get the response:

```
$ curl -v -H "content-type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google/redirect
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:3000...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /auth/google/redirect HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.71.1
> Accept: */*
> content-type: application/json
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';block-all-mixed-content;font-src 'self' https: data:;frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests
< X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
< Expect-CT: max-age=0
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
< X-Download-Options: noopen
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< X-RateLimit-Limit: 100
< X-RateLimit-Remaining: 98
< Date: Sun, 30 May 2021 01:48:38 GMT
< X-RateLimit-Reset: 1622339539
< Location: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fredirect&scope=email%20profile&client_id=604620607227-j25at9l5bjmqkdpfjoqb9ttu4b2v6tu9.apps.googleusercontent.com
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
< 
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

It doesn't show any user payload.

Why does curl or Postman is not responding with the user data? What i'm missing or not understanding about http, etc?

Finally, what's the proper way to send a http request from Angular in order to get user data and acces token?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: If its working in a browser and not via curl or postman, it is most likely because you are already logged into their service and/or it is submitting a cookie along with the request which is helping them identify you. Therefore they redirect back to you with payload without asking you to login. Without that context, they would ask you to login first.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Yes. I'm logged into, but how to make sure the access token and the user profile are available in the redirect page?

Comment: Solved by adding express-types